# HTML: Screen stutters during scrolling when crossing sticky text thats fixed at top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried searching stack overflow thinking that surely someone would have asked this noob question already. I couldn't find the solution to this hence posting as new question.
I have a HTML code that I need to show as a report.

```
<html>
<style>
body {
    background-color: rgb(59, 75, 84);
    font-family:      arial, verdana, trebuchet, officina, sans-serif;
    margin: 1; }

.top-container {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}

.mid-container {
    background-color: rgb(38, 52 ,63);
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: left;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    background: rgb(25, 165, 88);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    position:relative;
    margin: 1;
    z-index: 100;
}

.mid-container {
    padding: 1px;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .mid-container {
    position:absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top:auto;
}

table
{
    margin-bottom:    10px;
    vertical-align:   top; 
    border:           0;
    border-spacing:   1px;
    padding:          2px;
}

.HeadingTable
{
    width:            100%;
    text-align:       center;
    margin-top:       15px;
    margin-bottom:    30px;
    margin-left:      auto;
    margin-right:     auto;
    background-color: rgb(220, 221, 222);
}

.SubHeadingTable
{
    width:            100%;
    text-align:       center;
    margin-top:       15px;
    margin-bottom:    25px;
    background-color: rgb(220, 221, 222);
}

.ResultTable
{
    width:          100%;
    text-align:     left;
    padding-right:  20px;
}

table.ResultTable td
{
    vertical-align: top;
}

.OverallResultTable
{
    width:         50%;
    text-align:    center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left:   auto;
    margin-right:  auto;
    font-weight:   bold;
}

.TableHeadingCell
{
    background-color: rgb(179, 179, 179);
    font-family:      arial, verdana, trebuchet, officina, sans-serif;
    font-weight:      bold;
    text-align:       center;
}

.CellNoColor
{
    text-align:     left;
    vertical-align: top;
}   

.DefaultCell
{
    background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    text-align:       left;
}

.NumberCell
{
    background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    text-align:       center;
    min-width:        50px;
}

.PositiveResultCell
{
    text-align:       center;
    background-color: rgb(25, 165, 88);
}

.NegativeResultCell
{
    text-align:       center;
    background-color: rgb(240, 0, 0);
}

.WarningCell
{
    text-align:       center;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.NegativeResult
{
    background-color: rgb(240, 0, 0);
    text-align:       center;
    font-weight:      bold;
}

.PositiveResult
{
    background-color: rgb(25, 165, 88);
    text-align:       center;
    font-weight:      bold;
}

.Heading1
{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:   26px;
}

.Heading2
{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:   20px;
}

.Heading3
{
    font-family:   arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:   bold;
    font-size:     18px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top:    20px;
}

.Heading4
{
    font-family:   arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:   bold;
    font-size:     16px;
    margin-top:    10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.Heading5
{
    font-family:   arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:   bold;
    font-size:     14px;
    margin-top:    8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

p
{
    Margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.TestGroupHeadingBackground
{
    background-color: rgb(179, 179, 179);
}

.Indentation
{
    margin-left:  20px;
}

</style>

<head>
    <title>NVM Comparision Report</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="top-container">
        <h1>NVM Memory Comparision Report</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="header" id="myHeader">
        <h2>Overall Report Passed</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="mid-container">
        <h3>General Information</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="Heading4">Test Setup</div>
      <div class="Indentation">
        <table cellpadding="10">
            <td class="CellNoColor">Report Generation: </td>
            <td class="CellNoColor">Success</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="CellNoColor">File's Root Path: </td>
            <td class="CellNoColor">New XXX Path:   XXX</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="CellNoColor">Configuration Comment: </td>
            <td class="CellNoColor">XXX</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="CellNoColor">XXX: </td>
            <td class="CellNoColor">XXX</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="Heading4">Blocks Present in DataConfig</div>

      <div class="Heading5">New Version:0042</div>
        <div class="Indentation" style="float: none;">
          <table cellpadding="5" width = "70%">
            <tr>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="18%">Dataset Name</th>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="12%" text-align:center;>SparePart Number</th>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell">Blocks Present</th>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Result</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="TableHeadingCell">All Datasets</td>
              <td class="DefaultCell" style = text-align:center;>All Sparepart Numbers</td>
              <td class="DefaultCell">   Blocks 81, 99, 115, 120, 121, 133</td>
              <td class="PositiveResult">Pass</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    <div class="Heading5">Old Version:0041</div>
        <div class="Indentation" style="float: none;">
          <table cellpadding="5" width = "70%">
            <tr>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="18%">Dataset Name</th>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="12%" text-align:center;>SparePart Number</th>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell">Blocks Present</th>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Result</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="TableHeadingCell">All Datasets</td>
              <td class="DefaultCell" style = text-align:center;>All Sparepart Numbers</td>
              <td class="DefaultCell">   Blocks 81, 99, 115</td>
              <td class="PositiveResult">Pass</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

      <div class="Heading4">Following Blocks are Missing in New FEE Dumps:</div>
      <div class="Indentation" style="float: none;">
          <table cellpadding="5" width = "70%">
            <tr>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="18%">File Name</th>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="12%" text-align:center;>SparePart Number</th>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell">Blocks Missing</th>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Result</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="TableHeadingCell">All Files</td>
              <td class="DefaultCell" style = text-align:center;>All</td>
              <td class="DefaultCell"></td>
              <td class="WarningCell" rowspan=2>Pass</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      <div class="Heading4">Following Blocks are Missing in Old FEE Dumps:</div>
      <div class="Indentation" style="float: none;">
          <table cellpadding="5" width = "70%">
            <tr>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="18%">File Name</th>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="12%" text-align:center;>SparePart Number</th>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell">Blocks Missing</th>
              <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Result</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="TableHeadingCell">All Files</td>
              <td class="DefaultCell" style = text-align:center;>All</td>
              <td class="DefaultCell"></td>
              <td class="WarningCell" rowspan=2>Pass</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

    <table cellpadding="5" class="SubHeadingTable">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <big class="Heading2">Detailed Comparision Between FEE DUMPs</big>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="Indentation"></div>
  <table cellpadding="5" class="TestGroupHeadingBackground">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <big class="Heading3">XXX : </big>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <div class="Indentation">
      <p>Report is based on data obtained from comparing files XXX and XXX in folder RdW.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Indentation"></div>
    <div class="Indentation">
    <table cellpadding="5" class="ResultTable">
      <tr>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="4%">Block ID</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="4%">Block Address</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Block Name</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Parameter Name</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="4%">Size</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="auto">Old Data</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="auto">New Data</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="8%">Result</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">3</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">0x03000100</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">4 Bytes</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="WarningCell">Value Changed</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">5</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">0x03000300</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">4 Bytes</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="WarningCell">Value Changed</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">45</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">0x03002F00</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">5 Bytes</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="WarningCell">Value Changed</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
</div>
       <div class="Indentation"></div>
  <table cellpadding="5" class="TestGroupHeadingBackground">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <big class="Heading3">XXX</big>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <div class="Indentation">
      <p>Report is based on data obtained from comparing files XXX and XXX in folder USA.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Indentation"></div>
    <div class="Indentation">
    <table cellpadding="5" class="ResultTable">
      <tr>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="4%">Block ID</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="4%">Block Address</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Block Name</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Parameter Name</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="4%">Size</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="auto">Old Data</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="auto">New Data</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="8%">Result</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">3</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">0x03000100</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">4 Bytes</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="WarningCell">Value Changed</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">5</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">0x03000300</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">Fbl_Global</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">4 Bytes</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="WarningCell">Value Changed</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">45</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">0x03002F00</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">ProdData</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">5 Bytes</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="WarningCell">Value Changed</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
</div>

    <table cellpadding="5" class="SubHeadingTable">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <big class="Heading2">End of Report</big>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="Heading4" style="text-align=right;">Author: XXX</div>

    <script>
        window.onscroll = function()
        {
            myFunction()
        };

        var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
        var sticky = header.offsetTop;

        function myFunction()
        {
            if (window.pageYOffset > sticky)
            {
                header.classList.add("sticky");
            }
            else
            {
                header.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

When I run it in IE or chrome, the "Overall Report Passed" sticky text becomes fixed at top, but the entire screen flickers a moment when crossing that transistion point. I can fix it for my screen by giving padding-top:63px instead of auto (unsure what auto does) inside .sticky + .mid-container {} block



Can anybody suggest me how I can avoid this flickering altogether+make is common for all screen sizes + resolutions?
I'm using IE 11 + Mozilla Firefox. Flickering only occurs when scrolling down from the sticky text (scrolling from "Overall Report Passed" to "General Information")

Comment: You basically changes from position:relative to fixed which gets the header out of the document flow therefor the other content will move upward hence the flickering you see.

Comment: I tried to define another class which acts as regular text. If window is scrolled beyond the sticky text, it becomes sticky. If its scrolled up, it becomes the regular text. -> didn't work. Scrambled up succeeding texts

Comment: I'm also facing another problem - when scrolling down the sticky text, it becomes very slightly enlarged. I think its enlarged coz its not taking into account the space used by the scroll bar and takes on the entire page area - unlike the rest of the webpage.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa: Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you doing is changing from position relative to absolute by adding this class `.sticky` which takes the header out of the document flow, at the same time  `.sticky + .mid-container` is applied which applies position absolute on the `div.mid-container` that's the cause of the stuttering you see, if instead just apply a margin on the `div.mid-container` so when the header gets outside the document flow the elements don't react to that, so a margin-top equals to the height of the header should do it.

```
.sticky + .mid-container {
    /* position:absolute; Removed */

    /* Added : 39px is the height of your header. */
    /* If this varies just include js to make it dynamic. */
    margin-top:39px; 
    overflow: auto;
    /* padding-top:auto; Removed : auto is not a valid value for padding */
}
```

---

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  // i figured it should be '>='
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(59, 75, 84);
  font-family: arial, verdana, trebuchet, officina, sans-serif;
  margin: 1;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mid-container {
  background-color: rgb(38, 52, 63);
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: left;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  background: rgb(25, 165, 88);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1;
  z-index: 100;
}

.mid-container {
  padding: 1px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.mid-container {
  margin-top: 39px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.HeadingTable {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: rgb(220, 221, 222);
}

.SubHeadingTable {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(220, 221, 222);
}

.ResultTable {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

table.ResultTable td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.OverallResultTable {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.TableHeadingCell {
  background-color: rgb(179, 179, 179);
  font-family: arial, verdana, trebuchet, officina, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.CellNoColor {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.DefaultCell {
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
  text-align: left;
}

.NumberCell {
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.PositiveResultCell {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(25, 165, 88);
}

.NegativeResultCell {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(240, 0, 0);
}

.WarningCell {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.NegativeResult {
  background-color: rgb(240, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.PositiveResult {
  background-color: rgb(25, 165, 88);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Heading1 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.Heading2 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.Heading3 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.Heading4 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.Heading5 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

p {
  Margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.TestGroupHeadingBackground {
  background-color: rgb(179, 179, 179);
}

.Indentation {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <h1>NVM Memory Comparision Report</h1>
</div>

<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h2>Overall Report Passed</h2>
</div>

<div class="mid-container" style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <h3>General Information</h3>
</div>

<div class="Heading4">Test Setup</div>
<div class="Indentation">
  <table cellpadding="10">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="CellNoColor">Report Generation: </td>
        <td class="CellNoColor">Success</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="CellNoColor">File's Root Path: </td>
        <td class="CellNoColor">New XXX Path: XXX</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="CellNoColor">Configuration Comment: </td>
        <td class="CellNoColor">XXX</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="CellNoColor">XXX: </td>
        <td class="CellNoColor">XXX</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="Heading4">Blocks Present in DataConfig</div>

<div class="Heading5">New Version:0042</div>
<div class="Indentation" style="float: none;">
  <table cellpadding="5" width="70%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="18%">Dataset Name</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="12%" text-align:center;="">SparePart Number</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell">Blocks Present</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Result</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TableHeadingCell">All Datasets</td>
        <td class="DefaultCell" style="t" ext-align:center;="">All Sparepart Numbers</td>
        <td class="DefaultCell"> Blocks 81, 99, 115, 120, 121, 133</td>
        <td class="PositiveResult">Pass</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="Heading5">Old Version:0041</div>
<div class="Indentation" style="float: none;">
  <table cellpadding="5" width="70%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="18%">Dataset Name</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="12%" text-align:center;="">SparePart Number</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell">Blocks Present</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Result</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TableHeadingCell">All Datasets</td>
        <td class="DefaultCell" style="t" ext-align:center;="">All Sparepart Numbers</td>
        <td class="DefaultCell"> Blocks 81, 99, 115</td>
        <td class="PositiveResult">Pass</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>






<table cellpadding="5" class="SubHeadingTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <big class="Heading2">Detailed Comparision Between FEE DUMPs</big>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>






<div class="Indentation"></div>
<table cellpadding="5" class="TestGroupHeadingBackground">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <big class="Heading3">XXX</big>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="Indentation">
  <p>Report is based on data obtained from comparing files XXX and XXX in folder USA.</p>
</div>
<div class="Indentation"></div>
<div class="Indentation">
  <table cellpadding="5" class="ResultTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="4%">Block ID</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="4%">Block Address</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Block Name</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Parameter Name</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="4%">Size</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="auto">Old Data</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="auto">New Data</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="8%">Result</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">3</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">0x03000100</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">4 Bytes</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="WarningCell">Value Changed</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">5</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">0x03000300</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">Fbl_Global</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">4 Bytes</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="WarningCell">Value Changed</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">45</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">0x03002F00</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">ProdData</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">5 Bytes</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="WarningCell">Value Changed</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<table cellpadding="5" class="SubHeadingTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <big class="Heading2">End of Report</big>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="Heading4" style="text-align=right;">Author: XXX</div>
```

---

## EDIT

Note i had to remove some of the markup so i can post the edit, it was exceeding the limit.

```js
// we get the header height then apply it as marginTop to
// .mid-container
// removed the .sticky + .mid-container{} styling
// because we don't know the height of the header
// so we can't hard code it.

window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  // i figured it should be '>='
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");

    document.querySelector('.mid-container').style.marginTop = header.getBoundingClientRect().height + "px";
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
    document.querySelector('.mid-container').style.marginTop = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(59, 75, 84);
  font-family: arial, verdana, trebuchet, officina, sans-serif;
  margin: 1;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mid-container {
  background-color: rgb(38, 52, 63);
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: left;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  background: rgb(25, 165, 88);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  /* For refrence */
  height: 300px;
}

.mid-container {
  padding: 1px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.mid-container {
  margin-top: 39px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.HeadingTable {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: rgb(220, 221, 222);
}

.SubHeadingTable {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(220, 221, 222);
}

.ResultTable {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

table.ResultTable td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.OverallResultTable {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.TableHeadingCell {
  background-color: rgb(179, 179, 179);
  font-family: arial, verdana, trebuchet, officina, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.CellNoColor {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.DefaultCell {
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
  text-align: left;
}

.NumberCell {
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.PositiveResultCell {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(25, 165, 88);
}

.NegativeResultCell {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(240, 0, 0);
}

.WarningCell {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.NegativeResult {
  background-color: rgb(240, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.PositiveResult {
  background-color: rgb(25, 165, 88);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Heading1 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.Heading2 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.Heading3 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.Heading4 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.Heading5 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

p {
  Margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.TestGroupHeadingBackground {
  background-color: rgb(179, 179, 179);
}

.Indentation {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <h1>NVM Memory Comparision Report</h1>
</div>

<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h2>Overall Report Passed</h2>
</div>

<div class="mid-container" style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <h3>General Information</h3>
</div>

<div class="Heading4">Test Setup</div>
<div class="Indentation">
  <table cellpadding="10">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="CellNoColor">Report Generation: </td>
        <td class="CellNoColor">Success</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="CellNoColor">File's Root Path: </td>
        <td class="CellNoColor">New XXX Path: XXX</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="CellNoColor">Configuration Comment: </td>
        <td class="CellNoColor">XXX</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="CellNoColor">XXX: </td>
        <td class="CellNoColor">XXX</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="Heading4">Blocks Present in DataConfig</div>

<div class="Heading5">New Version:0042</div>
<div class="Indentation" style="float: none;">
  <table cellpadding="5" width="70%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="18%">Dataset Name</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="12%" text-align:center;="">SparePart Number</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell">Blocks Present</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Result</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TableHeadingCell">All Datasets</td>
        <td class="DefaultCell" style="t" ext-align:center;="">All Sparepart Numbers</td>
        <td class="DefaultCell"> Blocks 81, 99, 115, 120, 121, 133</td>
        <td class="PositiveResult">Pass</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="Heading5">Old Version:0041</div>
<div class="Indentation" style="float: none;">
  <table cellpadding="5" width="70%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="18%">Dataset Name</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="12%" text-align:center;="">SparePart Number</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell">Blocks Present</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Result</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TableHeadingCell">All Datasets</td>
        <td class="DefaultCell" style="t" ext-align:center;="">All Sparepart Numbers</td>
        <td class="DefaultCell"> Blocks 81, 99, 115</td>
        <td class="PositiveResult">Pass</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>






<table cellpadding="5" class="SubHeadingTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <big class="Heading2">Detailed Comparision Between FEE DUMPs</big>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>






<div class="Indentation"></div>
<table cellpadding="5" class="TestGroupHeadingBackground">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <big class="Heading3">XXX</big>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="Indentation">
  <p>Report is based on data obtained from comparing files XXX and XXX in folder USA.</p>
</div>
<div class="Indentation"></div>
<div class="Indentation">
  <table cellpadding="5" class="ResultTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="4%">Block ID</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="4%">Block Address</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Block Name</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="10%">Parameter Name</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="4%">Size</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="auto">Old Data</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="auto">New Data</th>
        <th class="TableHeadingCell" width="8%">Result</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">3</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">0x03000100</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">4 Bytes</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="WarningCell">Value Changed</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">5</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">0x03000300</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">Fbl_Global</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">4 Bytes</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="WarningCell">Value Changed</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">45</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">0x03002F00</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">ProdData</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="NumberCell">5 Bytes</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;font-family: Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Courier New, monospace;" class="DefaultCell">XXX</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="WarningCell">Value Changed</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<table cellpadding="5" class="SubHeadingTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <big class="Heading2">End of Report</big>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="Heading4" style="text-align=right;">Author: XXX</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems to have fixed my problem. I have found another solution for this - adding position:sticky instead of relative or fixed solves this problem beautifully. There is absolutely no stutter or lag in this. But the problem is that its not supported in IE at all (chrome + Mozilla specific). I guess your answer solves this problem! I'll check in my work PC and update accordingly

Comment: Lol... I've just checked in my PC. Seems this is a temp fix only. This margin-top:39px; would work fine, but needs to reconfigured if I change the header margin or padding. Also, I still notice a very slight stutter during the transition. I'm afraid the position:sticky is currently the easiest way to resolve this without too much problem.

Comment: yes that value was the height of the header, and as i mentioned, if it varies, use JS and make it dynamic

Comment: Ooh ... can you give an example how i can do that? I'm a complete newbie in js as well as in HTML so any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Check the changes :)